# Do the Edomites, Moabites and Ammonites exist today?

Tags: exegesis, history, old-testament, prophecy

I'm not sure if this is the right site for this type of question but I'm asking this because the Bible makes frequent references to these nations in prophecies, some of which pertain to the future, especially in the Old Testament.

Apparently Psalm 83 is alluding to a futuristic war involving the Edomites, Moabites, Ammonites etc. attacking Israel, according to some commentators because no such war described in Psalm 83 has occurred in history yet.

Comment: A question which begins "is it possible that ..."  typically has an uninformative "yes" answer (unless the question itself is about something which is self-contradictory).